# JQuery Ajax, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have no idea how to get about this. Say I want to animate a comment that has just been posted, maybe making it fade in, how would I set an ID to it in Rails so that I could select it and animate it? Is it possible to apply IDs to things as they're created in order to animate them in rails?

edit

By the way, I don't know jQuery, Ajax or Ruby. I'm only getting by on previous programming experience and being able to work with tutorials. It's a miracle what I've been able to do in two weeks not knowing much about rails at all. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

create.js.erb

```
$("#commentwall").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'comments')) %>")
$("#commentlist").hide().fadeIn(600)
$("#textbox").val('')
```

in the comments partial

```
      <%= form_for(@wallpost, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => {
                        :id => 'commentform'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, :value => @user.id %>  
      <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'inputbox', :id => "textbox" %>
      <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'right btn' %>    
      <% end %>
```

I also have a html list of all the wallposts comments in the comments partial...I don't wanna post all the html. It's long

```
   <ol><% @user.received_wallposts.reverse.each do |r| %><li>
   <%= r.content %>
   </li>
  <% end %>
  </ol>
```

Comment: If you don't know jQuery, Ajax or Ruby. According to me, the first time that you have to do is learn what it is ruby, ruby syntax, the rules of writing ruby or anything related to ruby. My advice, you can try to go to [tryruby](http://tryruby.org), you will be able to understand a little about ruby.


For Ajax and jQuery, you could read this [Using Unobtrusive JavaScript and AJAX with Rails 3](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/)

Comment: @anonymousxxx thanks. I already read that, and I got the comments work with Ajax. Even threw in some random fadeIn jquery function I chained on. But it fades all the comments, obviously. I picked up enough Ruby reading the code of apps of other people on github. I don't know it, but I'm a 2nd year CS major, with experience in Java, Python, and C, so it's not intimidating to me at all. What I don't know how to do is just grab the newest comment and to only animate that. I know you can grab ids with jQuery, but how do you grab the newest comment?

Comment: @Omerta: If you already have 90% of the groundwork in place, *say that when posting the question*. Show us the code for what you have so we can help you with it. Tell us the *specific issue* you have problems with, not 'help how do I animate comments'.

Comment: @Omerta : `but how do you grab the newest comment?` I need your code that you have tried, Could you post your code to your question?

Comment: I have a create.js.erb file that updates the comments partials, and I added an ID to the list of comments and put a .hid().fadeIn() on that. It all works. I just would like to figure out how to get comment that's saved right after the create action so I could do a slide or something with it using jQuery. Fading in the whole list of comments isn't so bad, but a slide with just the most recent comment would be pretty cool. I've been up all day trying to build this web app from scratch with only two weeks of rails experience. My friend wants it done by sunday, so I have a lot of pressure on me.

Comment: Again, show us the code for your view and your Javascript.

Comment: @sevenseacat. I did. Thank you for trying to help now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Added an id to the ol and in the create.js.erb I have

Valid html, too, if you care for pleasing W3C.

```
$("#commentsingle li:first-child").first().hide().fadeIn(600)
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: If you have more than one instance of the `#commentsingle` selector, your HTML is invalid. IDs must be unique on a page.

Comment: who cares if HTML is invalid, anyway? From what I've noticed, it's never impacted how the page actually works so as long as it works, despite being invalid. Do you proudly put the W3C validator image on your webpages?

Comment: As a warning, insulting other users is not tolerated here, so please don't do this again.

Comment: Brad...tell others not to be stuck up. There was a thread on hackernews talking about programmers being stuck up and unhelpful because of some weird elitist attitude. I think they should get it back in their face when they act like that. Most of the people here are helpful, but you have some bad cases like cat lady. Shouldn't speak to people from a pedestal. Treat me with respect and you are treated with respect back.

Answer (score 4):

A question like this requires an essay in full response, so let me provide a synopsis here.

#### 1. Pick your battles

If you are just starting as a programmer, **don't spend time on flourishes when simplicity will do**. This is the sort of problem that will take you hours and will provide your users only the slightest touch of benefit.

#### 2. Setting up Rails/jQuery

I won't go through setting up Rails because there are a ton of tutorials out there, but jQuery is as easy as including the right jQuery files in your `<head>`. See the jQuery tutorials on how to get started.

#### 3. Fading an element using jQuery

First, you give a unique identifier, such as a class or ID to your element. Then, you do something like this in jQuery to make it fade in. For other animations, consider reading the jQuery UI documentation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myelement').fadeIn()
})
```

To grab the most recent element, you could try one of these:

```
$('.type:last').fadeIn();
$('#e_23').fadeIn();
$('.box').find('.type:last').fadeIn();
```

Comment: btw...thanks bro. You're cool in my book.